Using Laravel Passport for Both API Authentication and OAuth for Third-Party Websites
I am building a Laravel project where users can create accounts, and I want to use Laravel Passport for API authentication. Additionally, I want users to be able to log in to third-party websites using their account from my website (OAuth2 provider functionality).
I have installed Laravel Passport, but I’m not sure if it’s the right tool to handle both regular API authentication and OAuth2 for external websites. Can Laravel Passport effectively manage both use cases? If so, what are the best practices for setting it up?
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
•   Installed Laravel Passport using composer require laravel/passport
•   Followed the initial setup documentation

Can someone provide guidance or recommend a better approach?
